# How to write $(AX-B)^{T}(AX-B)$ into the form $(X-K)^{T}\Sigma(X-K)$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, least-squares

I have a problem in the derivation of matrix. Suppose

- $A$ is some $m \times n$ matrix, with $m>n$.
- $B$ is a $m \times 1$ vector.
- $X$ is a $n \times 1$ vector.

If we define $M=(A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T}$, then how do we write $$(AX-B)^{T}(AX-B)$$ into the form $(X-K)^{T}\Sigma(X-K)$, where $\Sigma$ is a matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do. Directly compare the terms on expansion:

$X^{T}A^{T}AX = X^{T} \Sigma X  \space\space(1)$

$X^{T}A^{T}B + B^{T}AX = X^{T} \Sigma K + K^{T} \Sigma X \space\space(2)$

$B^{T}B = K^{T} \Sigma K \space\space(3)$

From $(1)$ we get the following:

$\Sigma = A^{T}A \space\space(4)$

Plugging $(4)$ in $(2)$, we get:

$B = AK \space\space(5)$

Now, ideally we would want to use $A^{-1}$ here to get the expression for $K$, but since $m > n$, our matrix $A$ will not be invertible directly. Assuming $M$ to be the left pseudo-inverse of $A$:

$K = MB \space\space(6)$

Plug $(1)$ and $(6)$ in the second expression to verify.